# Foreach javascript conflict with prototype.js

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

Foreach returns an odd function if I try to include prototype.js, if not I include the script works correctly. The following the wrong output with prototype:

```
function each(iterator, context) {
    try {
        this._each(iterator, context);
    } catch (e) {
        if (e != $break) 
            throw e;
    }
    return this;
}
```

**UPDATE:** I appeased the problem with if (element.hasOwnProperty (array)) {} but I'm not satisfied because putting an else you display a lot of functions prototype. This is clearly a conflict, how I resolve the conflict?

Comment: The `$` might be the issue?

Comment: "*wrong output*" is vague and impossible to figure out.

Comment: Prototype has special meaning of `$` character, you should try renaming your `$break` to something else.

Comment: Can you give me an example with a foreach loop?

Comment: raina77ow I have no idea, it is a function prototype, which is displayed inside my foreach loop.